# How to make plain http connection using HttpClient by passing an instance of java proxy class?

Tags: java, http, proxy, apache-httpclient-4.x

I want to make a HTTP connection by using HttpClient.

I didn't find any good examples which takes an instance of Java proxy class and pass as an argument to HttpClient to establish a plain HTTP connection.

I don't need to perform any get or post method on it. I'm new to this, so I would really appreciate a head start.